# The trouble with frames, selectors. Selenium + python

Tags: python, selenium, frames

using : Python (Visual studio code (last edit)) and Selenium(FireFox)

i have a problem with changing frames and working with them. It was on the first project with frames that I came across a non-standard one, hence even with wiki selenium I don't understand how to solve it.

[Site where i work](https://www.gmailnator.com/inbox/tyllerthomastmp/17eb7cb435f55912) I need to get a link from the [button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vJnD.jpg), but with this, a huge problem of working with frames appears for me, because the selector is different from the examples that I found.

Help me please =((

Answer (score 0):

```
wait=WebDriverWait(driver,60)
driver.get('https://www.gmailnator.com/inbox/tyllerthomastmp/17eb7cb435f55912')
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@id='message-body']")))
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//a[contains(text(),'e-mail')]"))).click()
```

Simply switch to that iframe and click the a text with that value.

Import:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```